# A way to retrieve data by address (c++)

Tags: c++

Using c++, is it possible to store data to a file, and retrieve that data by address for quicker access? I want to get around having to parse or iterate large files of data, with the ability to gain direct access to a subset of that data. In your answers, it does not matter how the data is stored; whatever works best with the answer you have.

Comment: You mean store it in memory and read it from there? Sure you can ;)

Comment: Can you try to specify?

Comment: I need to store it permanently. But maybe load it to virtual memory for address access?

Comment: What is hard memory? Hard drive?

Comment: You're asking about arbitrary offsets you want to use for file streams? Check out [`std::fstream::seekg()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Assuming you're using iostreams, you can use `tellg` and `tellp` to retrieve the current get and put (i.e., read and write) locations respectively. You can later feed the same value back to `seekg` or `seekp` to get back to the same location (again, for reading or writing respectively).

You can use these to (for one example) create an index into a file. Before writing each record to your primary data file, you'd use `tellp` to retrieve the current location. Then you'd store the data to the data file, and save the value `tellp` returned into the index file.  Depending on what sort of index you want, that might just contain a series of locations, so you can seek directly to record #N in the data file (even if the records are of different sizes).

Alternatively, you might store the data for some key field in the index file. For example, you might have a main data file with a set of records about people. Then you might build a number of indices into that, one with last names and a location for each, another with birthdays and a location for each, and so on, so you can search by name or birthday (or do an intersection between them to support things like `people older than 18 with a last name starting with "M", "N" or "O"`).

Comment: Care to expand with an example?

Comment: I'm going to look into this. It looks like what I need. I just could word it right to find the answer through google. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the further elaboration. This is perfect man, I really appreciate it.